# Firestore (update, delete, add) trigger to create Algolia Index takes too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I'm building an app using Algolia and Firebase.

To use Algolia, I'm using the following [firebase extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search) so that everytime new data is added, edited, updated to firestore, the same record is kept in Algolia.

Everything works well except it takes around 1-2 minute to store the record in Algolia (currently has around 15000+ records).

I'm currently reading and displaying data straight from Algolia and updating it whenever the data gets changed. However it seems absurd to wait 1-2 minutes before user can finally see the updated details.

I'm using Algolia because I need more flexible search options + page offset pagination. If I could do that with just firestore, I would happily just read data straight from firestore.

But since that's not possible **Can anyone see a better option?**

I've already tried writing a custom trigger instead of the extension but the speed seems to be the same.

Comment: Are you saying the your Cloud function takes 2 minutes to add data in Algolia or the time Algolia takes to index them?

Comment: After data is successfully added to firestore , it takes 1-2 minutes to be indexed and stored in Algolia. Hence I cannot search or view the data prior to that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be the expected behaviour. Algolia's documentation has a dedicated page for that topic:
[Why aren't my objects immediately available for search after being added?](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/troubleshooting/why-arent-my-objects-immediately-available-for-search-after-being-added/).

> When you add or update a record, our servers reply to your request as soon as they understand the operation, but the actual indexing starts a few seconds later, asynchronously.

They also say it may take a few seconds (or minutes) for the new documents to be available. You can read more about [how fast is the indexing?](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/index-configuration/how-fast-is-the-indexing/). It says, indexing may be slower on shared clusters. Upgrading to dedicated clusters may be helpful. That being said, time taken for indexing does not depend on whether you are using the extension, custom cloud function or your own servers to add data in Algolia.

Comment: do you think it's a good idea to just manually update the data in client side if there is no error and make it look like it updated or I should just let them hanging for 1-2minutes?

Comment: @Min what do you mean by manually update data in client? I'm not sure what kind of search you have there. But I don't see a minute or 2 to be a large duration. You can add a notice, "It might take a minute or two for your updates to show up in search" or something similar.

Comment: I'm not just using Algolia for search but I'm also retrieving the whole dataset from Algolia. For example, I read a list of 15000+ data User record not from firestore but from Algolia. My main concern is not searching but when I update, delete, add user records. If I add a new record, it immediately get stored in firestore but  not in Algolia. Hence I cannot fetch the newly added user record untill then. So what I'm thinking of doing is since I have already fetched the data without the new record, I just add the new record assuming it will successfully get stored in Algolia.

Comment: @Min if searching is not a concern then if I assume your dataset is an array of objects, when a user adds a new document just push that new doc object into that dataset array locally. That'll work perfectly. Hopefully the next time you load the dataset from Algolia after  refresh, that new doc will be there :)

Comment: Cool.  I was just wandering if it's okay to push it locally even though the data is not really there.  Is it bad practice or is it quite common to do so?

Comment: @Min I don't really see an issue in that. But if you need to make that data available across many users, then you should consider adding a Firestore listener in all client so they'll receive a copy of that new data directly from Firestore. If the data is limited to that user only then that shouldn't be a concern.